# How to find all possible $(x,y)$ values for which the condition $ x^2 + y^2 - 1 == 0$ is satisfied?

Tags: output-formatting, table

For equation of a circle, I need to find all possible $(x,y)$ values so that $x^2 + y^2 == 1$ or $x^2 + y^2- 1== 0$ is satisfied.

For the below written code, I am getting (x,y) values for which $x^2 + y^2- 1== 0$ is true and also (x,y) values for which $x^2 + y^2- 1== 0$ is false.

```
data = Table[{Evaluate[x^2 + y^2 - 1 == 0], x, y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

and obtained (x,y) values are

```
{{{False, -1, -1}, {True, -1, 0}, {False, -1, 1}}, {{True, 0, -1}, {False, 0, 0}, {True, 0, 1}}, {{False, 1, -1}, {True, 1,  0}, {False, 1, 1}}}
```

As we can see for (x,y)=(-1.0),(0,-1),(0,1),(1,0) only , $x^2 + y^2- 1== 0$ is true or satisfied.

But I just want to get a data table containing only those (x,y) values for which $x^2 + y^2- 1== 0$ is true. How can I get that table?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! You do know that there are _infinitely many_ points lying on the circle, right? Which points do you want to get? Do you want to sample them equidistantly along the perimeter?

Comment: @Domen yes, you are right.

Comment: How about using a Table? ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4vxd.png)   you can change the increment as there are infinity such points.

Comment: @Nasser But for that data table, I am not getting a circle , rather getting a half circle. No data points found in lowerhalf. Why is it so?

Comment: I only used half of the solution. To get the rest do screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKGCh.png)  code: `Table[{y,Sqrt[1-y^2]},{y,-1,1,.1}]; Table[{y,-Sqrt[1-y^2]},{y,-1,1,.1}]`

Comment: @TanmayeePatra, look at [`CirclePoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CirclePoints.html). For example, `CirclePoints[10]` gives you a list of 10 points on a circle.

Comment: @Domen that is a good suggestion. I forgot about it. Will delete my answer as this is a better solution as it gives same distance between points.

Comment: @Nasser, honestly, I still don't know what the OP wants ...

Comment: `x=Cos[t],y=Sin[t]`

Answer (score 2):

If you want answers with Integer x and y, you can use

```
Reduce[x^2 + y^2 - 1 == 0, {x, y}, Integers]
```

which returns the four that you already know. If you want real numbers x and y:

```
Reduce[x^2 + y^2 - 1 == 0, {x, y}, Reals] 

-1 <= x <= 1 && (y == -Sqrt[1 - x^2] || y == Sqrt[1 - x^2])
```

so x take on any value between -1 and +1, and y will be Sqrt[1-x^2] or -Sqrt[1-x^2].